# Why is my cube material just black in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created two cubes in unity (to act as walls) and when dragging the material onto the cube I just get a black surface. Here's a screenshot of the issue I'm having and this is Unity 2019 (I have had this working in Unity 2018 so I'm guessing that makes a difference) - all the properties for my material are shown in the screenshot.

[image: Material example - unity]

Answer (score 0):

change from legacy to standard surface shader

edit check if there is a light in scene or toggle the view option to jnlit and double check if thats the issue

Comment: i edited my answer for something else for you to check

Comment: I have directional light in there and even when I move it right next to the wall it's still just black

Comment: can you screenshot your material? also for directional light the position won't effect the lighting , just the rotation